# Legacy array notation not allowed on variable-arity parameter

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, variadic-functions

I'm asking this out of curiosity as I have not found a question to this specific compile error on StackOverflow:

> Legacy array notation not allowed on variable-arity parameter

I've come across legacy notation when seeing some code containing a signature like this:

`private void a(int ints[]){/*...*/}`

So I played around a bit until I encountered the compile error in the following samples.

```
// this method compiles as expected
private void method1(int[][] ints){ /*...*/ }

// this too
private void method2(int[]... ints){ /*...*/ }

// this does to, but makes use of legacy array notation
private void method3(int ints[][]){ /*...*/ }

// this still does, even when mixing up the notations
private void method4(int[] ints[]){ /*...*/ }

// this however fails to compile
private void method5(int... ints[]){ /*...*/ }
```

Is there a specific reason, that the language designer decided to implement it that way? To not allow varargs with legacy array notation?

> **NOTE**: I understand the legacy notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know *why* they decided to do this*, however, I'd just like to confirm that this is a formal part of the specification and is fully intended to produce a compile-time error:

> It is a compile-time error to use mixed array notation
>   ([§10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2))
>   for a variable arity parameter.

From [JLS 8.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)

<sub>*that question would be opinion-based since no one besides the Java language designers could tell you. If I were to speculate, it's likely because allowing multiple notations in the first place was a kind of bad idea.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

`int[] a` , `int a[]` are the same thing ,

so 1 ,3  and 4  are equivalent.

In 2, you are basically saying "i want a varargs of type int[]"

so it can be called like `method2(new int[]{},new int[]{})`.

In 5, `int..` tells the compiler that it's a vararg of type `int` and the name of the parameter is taken as `ints[]` ,which is invalid variable name.